# Android upgrading free app to paid app using sharedUserId

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a paid app out in the market currently. Now I want to provide a free app for the users to try out first. I also want to be able to ensure that the data created by the users of the free app would be visible once they upgrade to the paid app.

Having gone through the Android docs, it seems like using sharedUserId in Manifest would work.

The problem I have discovered is that if I put the sharedUserId in the Manifest of the paid app of version 2 then its older version (version 1) would not work since the data is no longer visible to the new app with the sharedUserId. Note that in version 1, I didn't implement the sharedUserId.

So now I am wondering if there is another workaround that I can implement so that:
a) the older version (without sharedUserId) of the paid app would still work with the new version (with sharedUserId).

b) the upgrade path from free version to paid version would include data remaining visible.

Anyone? It seems like that someone must have come across a similar situation and found a solution?

Answer (score -1):

My solution is to expose the data using a simple [Content Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) in the free app, sharing a password with the full app to avoid security holes.

**Free App: AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<provider android:name="MY_PACKAGE.PrefProvider" android:authorities="MY_PACKAGE.prefprovider" />
```

**Free app: PrefProvider.java**

```
public class PrefProvider extends ContentProvider {

    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        if (! selection.equals(MY_SECRET)) {
            return null;    //Wrong shared secret
        }
        MatrixCursor prefs = new MatrixCursor(new String[] {"field1", "field2", "field3"});         
        MatrixCursor.RowBuilder rb = prefs.newRow();
        rb.add(settings.getString("field1", ""));
        rb.add(settings.getString("field2", ""));
        rb.add(settings.getString("field3", ""));       
        return prefs;
    }

}
```

**Paid app: Main Activity**

```
    if (isFirstTime) {
        //  Is the first time that the full version is being launched
        Cursor cursor = act.getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://MY_PACKAGE.prefprovider"), null, providerKey, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() != false) { // non empty cursor, the free app is installed
            field1 = cursor.getString(0);
            field2 = cursor.getString(1);
            field3 = cursor.getString(2);
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The link you included gives a 404. Please add the relevant information to your answer directly.